# Why representations become functions?

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to answer Problem 5 below, but why irreducible representations become functions(i.e. $f_{m}$), aren't representations homomorphisms from $G$ to $GL(V)$?

[image]

(It would also be helpful if anyone could solve this problem for me,
since I even don't know what is the problem talking about)

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is one-dimensional then $GL(V)$ is naturally isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}^\times$, so one-dimensional representations can just be treated as functions $G\rightarrow\Bbb{C}^\times$. Then you need to ask yourself why all of these representations should be one-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the proof is:

1. Show that all irreps are one dimensional.
2. Show that one-dimensional irreps correspond to maps $S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}$.
3. Show that the only possible maps are as given above.

The first step is to show that every irreducible representation is 1 dimensional. Let $V$ be an irreducible complex representation. Using the terminology of the problem, pick a generator for $S^{1}$ $x$. Then, $x$ has an eigenvalue and hence stabilizes some one dimensional subspace $W$. But then the group generated by $x$ stabilizes $W$. Since this group is dense in $S^{1}$, this means that $S^{1}$ stabilizes $W$ (since the pre-image of $W$ under the action $S^{1} \times V \rightarrow V$ must be closed). Hence, $W$ is a subrepresentation of $V$, which by irreducibility of $V$, must be all of $V$.

Now, as mentioned in one of the answers above, one dimensional representations correspond to functions $S^{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$. However, any root of unity in $S^{1}$ must map to a root of unity in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}.$ Again, the set of roots of unity in $S^{1}$ is dense. So, one dimensional representations actually correspond to maps $S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}$.

To do the final step, we need to study homomorphisms from $S^{1}$ to itself. This can be done by looking at Lie algebra homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself and then seeing which ones integrate to $S^{1}$. It's is pretty clear that the Lie algebra homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself are precisely the vector space maps i.e. maps $x \mapsto \alpha x$ for some constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. For this to descend to a map from $S^{1}$ to itself, it must preserve the integers. Hence, $\alpha$ must be an integer. We now have all we need to figure out the corresponding map from $S^{1}$ to itself. using the exponential notation, we have

$$e^{2 \pi i \theta} \mapsto e^{2 \pi i \alpha \theta} = (e^{2 \pi i \theta})^{\alpha}$$

which is of the desired form, as $\alpha$ is an integer.

Comment: This problem by the way, is essentially the content of Fourier analysis on complex valued periodic functions on the real line. Here's a not fully rigorous picture of why that is the case. A periodic function of the real line is in fact just a map from $S^{1}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Since $S^{1}$ is abelian, this is a class function. By the Peter-Weyl theorem (you have to be more careful here) the class functions corresponding to irreducible characters generate a dense subspace of all class functions. Hence, you can write any function $f$ as a convergent infinite sum of maps of the given form.

Comment: The full statement of Fourier analysis then just uses the orthonormality of irreducible characters to pick off the corresponding coefficient of $z \mapsto z^{n}$ (which on the real line looks like $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i nx}.)$